# Taking input to a variable from a textbox

Tags: winforms, powershell

I am working on creating a GUI based app with PowerShell. I am struggling with getting the text entered by the user in the textbox to be assigned to a variable.

I want the user to enter the server name in the textbox and use that text on button click for processing the rest.

Suppose `$Textbox` is the textbox while `$Server` is the server.

[image]

Comment: You would do well to read [ask] as your question is missing some of the basics.. specifically any code (as [mcve])

Comment: My bad, missed the screenshot. @JamesC.

Comment: Screenshot of the form window itself is fine, but please don't post screenshots of code - post the actual code (maybe revisit the "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" page linked by @JamesC.)

Comment: You probably want to research events. Keeping in mind you are now using .NET libraries within your powershell.... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button_events(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Please do NOT post screenshots of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the picture of what you posted... here is how you would handle the button click and passing the content of the textbox to the server function

```
function Server-Task {
    Param(
        [string]$textboxStuff
    )
    # ... Do Stuff ....
}

$Submit.Add_Click({Server-Task $Textbox.Text})
```

You could also just store the `$Textbox.Text` to a variable

Comment: Was able to use $Textbox.text and assigned it to th variable I wanted. $Server = $Textbox.Text
write-host $Server

Comment: Yes I used the $Textbox.text into a variable and then worked with the variable for my result-set.

Comment: @RamakantDadhichi Glad you were able to get it working. Did you get the button click working?

Comment: Yes,the app is working fine now. Will add more features soon.

Comment: @RamakantDadhichi Please remember to mark the answer so that others with similar questions know this worked

Comment: Sure, Thanks for editing the answer I was about to do that. Cheers!! You showed me the way to proceed.